Where is the mistake in this line integral evaluation?
Consider the vector function
$$ \vec{f}(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} y \\  x \end{bmatrix} \tag{1} $$
The goal is to evaluate the line integral
$$ \int_{(0,0)}^{(a,b)} \vec{f}(x,y)\cdot d\vec{x} \tag{2} $$
with $\vec{x}=[x~y]^{T}$.
We can immediately see that
$$ \vec{f}(x,y) = \nabla (xy) \tag{3} $$
which means $g(x,y)=xy$ is a potential for f. Hence, the integral is path-independent (which justifies writing it like (2) in the first place) and
$$ \int_{(0,0)}^{(a,b)} \vec{f}(x,y)\cdot d\vec{x} = \int_{(0,0)}^{(a,b)} dg(x,y) = g(a,b)-g(0,0)=ab \tag{4}$$
Alternatively, (2) can be explicitly written out:
$$ \int_{(0,0)}^{(a,b)} (ydx+xdy) = \int_{(0,0)}^{(a,b)} ydx + \int_{(0,0)}^{(a,b)} xdy =ab+ab = 2 ab \tag{5} $$
So it seems that there is a mistake somewhere, probably in (5). What is the precise reason this does not work? Is it true that one can split otherwise path-independent integrals into path-dependent ones? (I guess not, but why not?)
I am looking for an anylysis of the mistake I have made here. What can I learn from this when working with line integrals?
Edit 1:
Following the comments, I will try a parametrization with  $\vec{x}(t)=t [a~b]^{T}$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}= [a~b]^{T}$:
$$ \int_{(0,0)}^{(a,b)} \vec{f}(x,y)\cdot d\vec{x}
= \int_{0}^{1} \vec{f}(at,bt)\cdot \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} dt
= 2ab \int_0^{1} t dt = ab$$
which, as expected, gives the correct result. Interestingly, there appears a factor $2ab$, which is then canceled from the $\frac{1}{2}$ of the integration over $t$.

You need to learn how to calculate line integrals correctly. Do evaluate the line integral directly, you must parametrize the path by $(x(t),y(t))$ and convert to a $t$ integral.

@TedShifrin So is even the first step of (5) not allowed, i.e. separating $dx$ and $dy$ like this; or rather, directly/naively evaluating the dot product?

I recommend setting up the line integral correctly by parameterizing as @TedShifrin suggested then comparing it to your other calculations. See if you can identify which steps are correct or incorrect after that.

Separating is fine. But when you integrate $\int y,dx$ you need to write everything in terms of the parametrization. Go learn the definition!

My electromagnetism professor issued this problem few months ago when computing the work to bring a charge from some point to another point. It turns out when you do it applying what you do in $(5)$ you're actually doing the same work twice. To avoid this problem you should parametrize the path as @Ted Shifrin has mentioned.

For instance if you're transporting your charge radially, $y=\dfrac{b}{a}x$, and thus,
$$\int x,\mathrm dy+\int y,\mathrm dx=2\dfrac{b}{a}\int_0^a x,\mathrm dx=ab$$

Where does the splitting and naive integration add the factor 2 then?

Naive integration makes zero sense. $x$ and $y$ are not independent variables.

@TedShifrin Why not? Is that because this is a line integral and one needs a path between the endpoint where then $x$ and $y$ are connected? Also, if this integral as appearing there was not a line integral, but a sum of two regular integrals $\int x dy$ and $\int y dx$, would they still be connected or can they be computed separately?
